# How are bands completely regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

In Howie's Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory, he states that any band $B$ is completely regular if we define $x'=x$, which gives us the identities $(x')'=x$, $xx'x=x$, and $xx'=x'x$. I don't understand what $x'$ is supposed to be, is it an inverse of $x$? And if it is, how does it make sense to just define what the inverse is, without considering the binary operation $B$ is equipped with?

See

*Howie, John M.*, Fundamentals of semigroup theory, London Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series. 12. Oxford: Clarendon Press. x, 351 p. (1995). [ZBL0835.20077](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0835.20077). : p. 113, Section 4.4 Bands (paragraph before it, and start of the paragraph after the section starts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [completely regular semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_semigroup) is a semigroup where every element belongs to a subgroup of that semigroup.
Since bands are idempotent semigroups, i.e., a semigroup is a band iff it satisfies the equation
$$x \cdot x \approx x,$$
it follows that, in rather trivial way, each element of the band is part of a subgroup of the band (semigroup):
the sub-semigroup $\langle \{x\}, \cdot \rangle$ has the structure of group if we define $x$ to be the unit and the inverse to be the identity map.
Indeed, this structure satisfies any identity that you can com up with in the language of semigroups.

So yes, $x'$ denotes the inverse of $x$ (only within that singular subgroup of the band), and the binary operation is the same as the one of the band.